# Instead of these buttons, how can I turn it into a sidebar menu?

Tags: html, css

I have this html file which defines the admin home page. It has buttons, as you can see, such as view personal information, view expense claims etc. At the moment, all these buttons are just displayed in the middle of the screen. Can someone please tell me what things to add to the .css file to turn these buttons into a sidebar menu? Much appreciated, thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "main.css">
  <title>Admin Home Page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="MainpageOptions" method="post">
    <h1>
Admin Home Page
</h1>

    <input type="submit" value="View Personal Information" name="vpi">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="View Expense Claims" name="vec">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="View Payslips" name="vps">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Change Password" name="cp">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Maintain Employee Information" name="mei"> 
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Maintain Tax Information" name ="mti"> 
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type = "submit" value="Maintain Payroll Items" name = "mpi"> 
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type = "submit" value = "Maintain Timesheet" name = "mts"> 
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type = "submit" value = "Maintain Employee Expenses" name = "mee"> 
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type = "submit" value = "Run Payroll" name = "rpy"> 
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type = "submit" value = "Generate Reports" name = "grp">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/plac3bodk/8com4m5r/) out.

Just added a DIV around the whole menu and added the following CSS

```
<div id="adminSidebar">
#adminSidebar{float:left;background:lightgrey;}
#adminSidebar input{padding:5px;margin-bottom:5px;width:100%}
```

You can play with the styling as you please, but this is just a simple example

Comment: Hi plac3bodk. Thanks for this! But, the lightgrey background isn't being applied properly. It doesn't encompass all the buttons. Do you know any parameters that can fix this?

Comment: What I mean is, is there a way to make the entire left side of the screen lightgrey background colour? And also make the buttons such that they are not individual buttons, but part of one sidebar? like this: [link](http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Sticky-Sidebar-Navigation-Menu-with-jQuery-Vertical-Navigation.jpg)

Comment: Really the only thing for it (as plac3bodk said) is to play around with the styles of your various pieces - margins, padding, height, the button style, etc until it looks how you want. Sure it can take all day, but that's how life is working with css!

Comment: @Ciara Haha yea, once I establish the css I can apply it to all the pages and then continue working on the actual functionality of the payroll system (it's a high school project)

Comment: Hi again
The reason is that input buttons have some default styling as you see in the example.
So you need to style the inputs to get rid of the default styling.
Is there a specific reason why you are using input buttons, because if not, I'd suggest making the menu s an unordered list with a href links.
Check [this](http://webexpedition18.com/articles/how-to-create-a-simple-drop-down-menu-with-css3/) and dont think about the dropdown functionality, just the styling.
I think this is close to what you're looking for

Comment: @plac3bodk But this doesn't implement `  <form action="MainpageOptions" method="post">`

Comment: True that.
Then there was a specific reason :D
Well the tut I sent you, should still rather easy to apply to your form.
Just keep adding styles to your #adminSidebar input